# How to fix Normal Map Artifacts (Humanoid)

Tags: normal-map, artifacts

After baking my normal map from my high poly humanoid model, and applying to my retopo'd model, I'm getting artifacts around the groin/thigh and fingers.

Without Cage:
[image]

Cage:
[image]
[image]

I'm new to this process, and have spent a few hours just messing about with the ray distance, margin, and even adding more edge loops etc. Also tried using a displaced cage to no effect.

Was really excited to finish my first sculpt in blender and was looking forward to using it in game on the low poly model, and artifacts happens... Any help here would be appreciated, thanks!

FYI: Newish to blender (tried it donkey years ago), and I got to say, I'm really enjoying 2.83. It's awesome!

Comment: can we have a picture of the cage in the problematic area?

Comment: @Mobin, Please see edited post with caged normal map. Thanks!

Comment: I think sometimes you can't avoid artifacts whatever solution you try, so the solution is either to give corrections to the normal map with good colors, or combine several normal maps into one.

Comment: @moonboots, combining several normal maps into one sounds like a plausible solution! I didn't think about that before, but I might have to go that route here if there's no better solutions presented. Thanks mate, I'll give it a try.

Comment: your cage seems very wrong can you zoom on the problematic areas you caged?

Comment: yeah, I realised the shrinkwrap was still on it... also did more research on how cages are done. I'll do a proper one that isn't just a quick displacement mod and report back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mobin for prompting me regarding my cage, I did some further research and found out the proper way to do a cage.

My steps to resolve artifactings:

1. Duplicate lowpoly model, and name as Cage
2. Select all faces of Cage, alt s, to scale up the faces in normal directions
3. Toggle on mirror selection mode
4. Compare Cage to High Poly model, and push out all faces to completely surround the High Poly. i.e. Cage should be slightly bigger than the High Poly
5. Ensure there are no overlapping faces, i.e. tight areas like fingers and groin can be problematic, and require quite abit of manual adjustments
6. Bake for a perfect normal map

[image]